# Bash How can I use read command to assign multiple words to 1 variable

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I am trying to get multiple words/arguments into one variable with read. I tried assigning it into an array and using while loop to put all the elements in the array into 1 string.

```
    read -a info
    i=0
    datastring=""
    while [ $i -lt ${info[@]} ] 
    do
        datastring=$datastring${info[i]}
    done
    echo "$dataString"
```

When I run the program it just doesn't do anything and sits there and won't print out datastring and I'm kinda lost on any other way to do it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Let's say `info` is 5, then `0 < 5` and you keep concatenating 5 onto a variable infinitely many times for some reason?

Comment: You never update `i` in your loop, and you want to compare it to `${#info[@]}` instead. But why read it into an array in the first place if you are just going to compress it into a single string anyway.

Comment: Okay its supposed to be a piece of script on creating a file of sorts supposed to be a single line with a number of fields in it. The command line gives the file name and type. This was test code to see if this worked, but obviously it didn't. I also hadn't figured out how to put a space in between each argument as well. That's kind of the point. As to why I'm doing this well kind of new to bash so I'm trying to learn how to do different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
read datastring <<<"this sentence contains multiple words"
echo "$datastring"
```

If you already have an array

```
datastring=${info[*]}
```

Will concatenate the array into a single word, using the 1st char of $IFS as a separator.  If you want the words all smushed together with no separators, you could do this:

```
datastring=""
for word in "${info[@]}"; do datastring+=$word; done
```

or this:

```
datastring=$(IFS=""; echo "${info[*]}")
```

or this:

```
datastring=${info[*]}
datastring=${datastring// /}
```

Note, all quotes and array indices (`*` vs `@`) have been carefully chosen: see
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion and
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays